# I tried to install Ubuntu following all the instructions, but still the installation says "you need at least 8.6gb..."

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, disk-usage

I am new to Ubuntu and recently I bought a new Dell Computer: Inspiron 13 5000 with 256 SSD, model i5379-5893GRY-PUS. I am trying to install Ubuntu.

I did try a lot of configurations, but none was successful. Things I already tried:

- Disable fast boot
- `powercfg off`
- AHCI enable
- Startup windows on safe mode and then restarting
- Disable security boot
- Partitioning on windows

I really don't know what else to try.

Commands:

$ fdisk -l

```
Disk /dev/loop0: 61.6 MiB, 64573440 bytes, 126120 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop1: 318.1 MiB, 333533184 bytes, 651432 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop2: 962 MiB, 1008779264 bytes, 1970272 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop3: 426.5 MiB, 447172608 bytes, 873384 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sda: 7.4 GiB, 7948206080 bytes, 15523840 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x4f4e129b

Device     Boot   Start     End Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *         64 3731283 3731220  1.8G cd unknown
/dev/sda2       3731284 3739475    8192    4M ef EFI (FAT-12/16/32)
```

$ lsblk -f (DONE USING MANJARO)

```
NAME   FSTYPE   LABEL    UUID                                 MOUNTPOINT
loop0  squashfs                                               /run/miso/sfs/livefs
loop1  squashfs                                               /run/miso/sfs/mhwdfs
loop2  squashfs                                               /run/miso/sfs/desktopfs
loop3  squashfs                                               /run/miso/sfs/rootfs
sda    iso9660  MJR17110 2018-05-07-20-05-15-00               /run/miso/bootmnt
├─sda1 iso9660  MJR17110 2018-05-07-20-05-15-00               
└─sda2 vfat     MISO_EFI FDB1-353B
```

$ ls -ltr /dev/sda*

```
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 0 Jul  4 05:36 /dev/sda
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 2 Jul  4 05:36 /dev/sda2
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 1 Jul  4 05:36 /dev/sda1
```

$ ls -ltr /dev/loop*

```
brw-rw---- 1 root disk  7,   7 Jul  4 05:36 /dev/loop7
brw-rw---- 1 root disk  7,   6 Jul  4 05:36 /dev/loop6
brw-rw---- 1 root disk  7,   5 Jul  4 05:36 /dev/loop5
brw-rw---- 1 root disk  7,   4 Jul  4 05:36 /dev/loop4
brw-rw---- 1 root disk  7,   2 Jul  4 05:36 /dev/loop2
brw-rw---- 1 root disk  7,   1 Jul  4 05:36 /dev/loop1
brw-rw---- 1 root disk  7,   0 Jul  4 05:36 /dev/loop0
crw-rw---- 1 root disk 10, 237 Jul  4 05:36 /dev/loop-control
brw-rw---- 1 root disk  7,   3 Jul  4 05:36 /dev/loop3
```

$ sudo lshw -C storage

```
*-usb:0                   
       description: Mass storage device
       product: USB Reader
       vendor: ChipsBnk
       physical id: 1
       bus info: usb@1:1
       logical name: scsi0
       version: 1.00
       serial: 110074973765
       capabilities: usb-2.00 scsi emulated scsi-host
       configuration: driver=usb-storage maxpower=100mA speed=480Mbit/s
  *-storage UNCLAIMED
       description: SATA controller
       product: Sunrise Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode]
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 17
       bus info: pci@0000:00:17.0
       version: 21
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 66MHz
       capabilities: storage msi pm ahci_1.0 cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:d1230000-d1231fff memory:d1234000-d12340ff ioport:f090(size=8) ioport:f080(size=4) ioport:f060(size=32) memory:d1233000-d12337ff
```

Comment: What did you choose in the installer to get to that point ?

Comment: Just selected language, keyboard style and the message appears

Comment: Show us the partitions, please.

Comment: the partitions are now in the post.

Comment: Your Ubuntu terminal view does not show any hard drive partitions, only the one on the USB.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Could you please post text files, dialogue messages, and program output listings as text, not as images? To achieve the latter two you can either 1) select, copy & paste the dialogue text or terminal content or 2) [save the program output to a file](//askubuntu.com/q/420981/175814) and use that. Longer listings (the editor will tell you what’s too long) should be uploaded to a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) and linked to in the question. Thanks.

Comment: Which Ubuntu release are you trying to install? Looks like Ubuntu doesn't recognise the storage controller. Could you please make sure that AHCI mode is selected in BIOS and [edit] your question to include the output of `sudo lsblk -f` and `sudo lshw -C storage`. Thanks.

Comment: Modifications done!